# Store properties in database, but override locally

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons-config

Currently, we store our application's environment properties in a .properties file in the WEB-INF.  We want to move them to a database table.  But we still want to specify the jndi name, and when running in our test environment locally, we want to be able to override certain properties just for our workspace for test and development.

Apache commons' DatabaseConfigurator seemed nice, but wouldn't play nice with the jndi name being defined as a property in the file.  Nothing I did to ask it to look at the property file first worked.

I decided to subclass apache commons' AbstractConfiguration to try to create a single configurator that would check the file and database as I wished, but again, it didn't really work.  Spring wants that jndi name absolutely first, probably because the data source has to be passed into the configurator as a parameter.

How can I get what I am after here?  Mostly properties in the database, but those that are in the file override them.  And jndi name for the datasource should not have to be hardcoded in the spring config.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a ApplicationContext listener that will read the configuration from your DB and inject them in the JNDI? Then you can override the configuration in the JNDI with a context.xml file that will be placed in the src/local/webapp/META-INF/.

This is how we get this working in our webapp.