# Spring config properties from database and properties

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons-config

I asked a similar question, but based on the responses, I did a bad job describing what I am after.  I have a spring 4 webapp that loads properties from a properties file.  We consume those properties both via the "${proper.name"} expressions in spring, as well as by injecting a properties object into some of our classes.

We want to move most of the properties to a database table and make them reloadable.  However, a few need to stay in local properties, potentially overriding the database setting.  These should also be loaded dynamically after the app is running.

I know that once a particular bean is injected, it won't get reloaded, that doesn't concern me, it's up to that module to handle that.  But I am having trouble getting the behavior I want.  In particular, I have implemented an AbstractConfiguration from apache commons configuration to get the dual source and overriding I am after.  But while it works for injecting the properties object, expressions loaded with "${prop.name}" don't work at all.

How can I get them to work?  Did I override the wrong thing?  Is it just some config detail?

```
<bean id="sysProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="databaseConfigurator" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="getProperties"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="databaseConfigurator" class="my.util.config.MyDatabaseConfigurator">
    <property name="datasource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="propertyFile" value="/WEB-INF/my.properties" />
    <property name="applicationName" value="ThisApp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dbConfigFactory" class="org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationConverter" factory-method="getProperties">
    <constructor-arg ref="databaseConfigurator" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store properties in database, but override locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850768/store-properties-in-database-but-override-locally)

Comment: I don't think it is because I asked that question and I think I did a bad job asking it.  The responder to that question got stuck on the jndi issue because I focused on it too much in the question.  The result is that I got no useful answers.  So I rephrased.  @JEY

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think it might work.

```
<bean id="sysProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="databaseConfigurator" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="getProperties"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="databaseConfigurator" class="my.util.config.MyDatabaseConfigurator">
    <property name="datasource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="propertyFile" value="/WEB-INF/my.properties" />
    <property name="applicationName" value="ThisApp" />
</bean>



<bean name="PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean"/>
</bean>

<bean name="CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean" class="org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean">
       <constructor-arg ref="databaseConfigurator"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: org.springmodules.commons http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springmodules/spring-modules-jakarta-commons

Comment: I hadn't tried that springmodules subpackage, but the results appear about the same (the ${} notation properties don't work including the jndi name on the datasource).  Is this basically a derivative of apache commons configuration?  MyDatabaseConfigurator inherits from org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.  Perhaps there is a springmodules variant I need to inherit from?

Comment: You need to add more detail to the question.  Where are you using ${} notation?  You also need to provide more detail about your spring config.  Are there multiple Spring Contexts involved?  Is the bean using ${} in the same context as the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Comment: We use ${} whenever we want a property injected.  Such as the jndi datasource name or the cron expression we use to prime our quartz tasks.  Works fine if I use a plain property file, doesn't work at all when I go to this database drive property file.  Only one spring context, so yes to the last question.  I can see the DB config loading the properties, and they are available in the 'sysProperties' as a whole when I inject that, but the quartz tasks don't start, and the jndi name is never recognized.  The jndi name makes sense since its on the datasource fed into this bean.

Comment: ...but even when I hardcode the jndi name in the spring config, the quartz tasks won't load...as if they received a null or blank cron expression.